# Jquery selecting dynamic id and execute that particular id

Tags: jquery

I want to execute the `keyup()` event for the dynamic generated Id's ----- Id's can be grid-1, grid-2 etc ---. So field count will be more, so i cannot able to add more code for each id --. So need a single code to execute it ---

I tried the below code --- it checks for the ids starting with 'grid-' but when the action completes the value gets changed in all the fields. so need to be specific with the field -----

```
$(document).on('keyup','input[id^="grid-"]',function(){
   $("input[id^='grid-']").val(this.value.match(/[0-9]*/));
});
```

Comment: `$(document).on('keyup','input[id^="grid-"]',function(){
   $(this).val($(this).val().match(/[0-9]*/));
});`

Comment: $(this).val($(this).value.match(/[0-9]*/));  --- throwing error -- cannot read the property match of undefined

Comment: Hey, thanks man... It works .. :) i made a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling up the `val()` on all input fields width id starting with `grid-`. You need to localize it to the input triggering the `keyup()` event.

```
$(document).on('keyup','input[id^="grid-"]',function(){
   $(this).val($(this).val().match(/[0-9]*/));
});
```

If you are using jQuery its better to stick on to it completely rather than mixing up native JavaScript with it.